# Как добавить видео в Java Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

Использую Spring Security, Spring MVC, Spring Data и Spring Boot. Мне надо дать возможность пользователю добавлять видео на сайт. Как это можно сделать? Слышал что-то про File Upload, но непонятно, как это можно применить.

Comment: нелюблю грубить, но можно начать давать книгу по орфографию

Comment: @SeniorPomidor думаю, что можно с понимание отнестись к тому, что русский - не родной язык для автора. Но вот постановка вопросов действительно расстраивает.

Comment: я не русский я из Испании просто хотел увидеть ответ на вопрос но если грамматика вам больше всего беспокоил пожалуйста лучше исправить я приму и мне будет крута и вопрос будет грамматно @SeniorPomidor спасибо вам

Comment: @Vigen.hovhannisyan, дело не в беспокойстве, а очень трудном понимании смысла при чтении.

Comment: @Vigen.hovhannisyan, попытался переформулировать вопрос. Надеюсь, я не исказил его смысла (если всё-таки исказил — дайте знать, исправлю).

Comment: @Vigen.hovhannisyan так может вам было бы проще на https://es.stackoverflow.com ?